# PostGresqL full-text Search characters problème

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Well my problem is : I am using the full-text search of postgresql with a french dictionnary, 
and I have in my data base some descriptions that contains names with one character for exemple : 
Amphi 'A' , Amphi 'C, Amphi 'D' ... 
well, for that, when I use tsvector auto creation trigger, somme names don't appear, 
for Amphi A I got 'amphi':1 'a':2 but for Amphi 'C' is 'amphi':1 without the it's name.

please help me :D

Comment: Can you show us the trigger, which generates the `tsvector` values? Are you using the `setweight()` & `to_tsvector()` like in the example in the docs? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-DOCUMENTS

Comment: Hello, thank u for the reply: here is the trigger : CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public."Structure"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('ts_vecteur', 'pg_catalog.french', 'description');

Comment: As I said, some characters are added but others not

Comment: So you don't want to weight your document with A...D; those are part of the documents?

Comment: I have 24  amphitheater named from a to x I need their names in my tsvector so I can search amphi a or amphi c but some names don't appear, I get only the word amphi

Comment: here's a sight of what I get https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztn5oo3kyomddoc/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 2):

That's because f.ex. `C` and `D` considered to be [stop words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS) in the french dictionary:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('french', 'Amphi A'); -- 'a':2 'amphi':1
SELECT to_tsvector('french', 'Amphi C'); -- 'amphi':1
```

You can create a custom dictionary (& a configuration for that) without stop words by:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY french_stem_nostop(
    TEMPLATE = snowball,
    LANGUAGE = 'french'
);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_nostop(COPY = french);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_nostop
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciihword WITH french_stem_nostop;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_nostop
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword WITH french_stem_nostop;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_nostop
    ALTER MAPPING FOR hword WITH french_stem_nostop;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_nostop
    ALTER MAPPING FOR hword_asciipart WITH french_stem_nostop;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_nostop
    ALTER MAPPING FOR hword_part WITH french_stem_nostop;

SELECT to_tsvector('french_nostop', 'Amphi C'); -- 'amphi':1 'c':2
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much, so I need to create a new dictionnary using the sql that u gave me and use it instead of the old one :D thant you very much sir

Comment: Exuce me, I am trying to use CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public."Salle"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('ts_vecteur', 'french_nostop', 'description'); after creating the dictionnary but an error appears

Comment: Yes, if your input is really (literally) has names like `C` or `D` -- but they're not ignored by accident: they are mostly irrelevant on that language, f.ex: `SELECT to_tsvector('french', 'c''est la vie'); -- 'vi':4`

Comment: First, you need to create the dictionary (& the configuration), before you use it. The dictionary (& the configuration) exists within a schema (if you use multiple schemas) -- make sure that schema is in the `search_path`, or use a schema-qualified name, like `'public.french_nostop'`. If you still not succeed, what is the error?

Comment: :D thank you very much, I had to add public.french_nostop and it worked