# I want ts_query to consider articles as well like a, an, the how to do that?

Tags: postgresql

This is my sql

```
    select *
    from 
    my_table
    where to_tsvector('english', description || keywords ) @@ to_tsquery('a|an|the|it');
```

**Records**

```
-------------------------------
| id |  Description            |
-------------------------------
| 1  |  this is a first record |
-------------------------------
| 2  |  its an second record   |
-------------------------------
| 3  |  a an the               |
-------------------------------
| 4  |  he she it they         |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: You can create custom full text search dictionaries, which don't use stop words. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991695/postgresql-full-text-search-characters-problème/23994141#23994141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `english` as the text search configuration, use `simple` instead.

**This one works**:

```
select to_tsvector('simple', 'a car') @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'a|an');
```

Result:

```
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

**This one doesn't work**:

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'a car') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'a|an');
```

Result:

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```